# ¿Cómo generar un TXT organizado con VBA?

Tags: base-de-datos, excel, vba, archivo, txt

Necesito generar un TXT de una tabla de excel la cual lleva solo números, pero la dificultad está en que las columnas del txt deben llevar el punto que separa lo decimales en la misma columna o espacio, como se ve en las siguiente imagen. Cabe decir que la tabla tiene un formato para que no aparezcan los 0 a la derecha del punto decimal, solo las decimas como en la ultima columna.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando el siguiente codigo en VBA y he probado muchos metodos y no logro el objetivo de organizar los puntos decimales.

```
Sub CreaTXT()

    Dim NombreArchivo, RutaArchivo As String
    Dim obj As FileSystemObject
    Dim tx As Scripting.TextStream
    Dim Ht As Worksheet
    Dim i, j, nFilas, nColumnas As Integer
    
    NombreArchivo = "DatosCaesar"
    RutaArchivo = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & NombreArchivo & ".txt"
    
    Set Ht = Worksheets("Datos")
    Set obj = New FileSystemObject
    Set tx = obj.CreateTextFile(RutaArchivo)
    
    nColumnas = Ht.Range("A1", Ht.Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Cells.Count
    nFilas = Ht.Range("A2", Ht.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count
    
    For i = 1 To nFilas
    
        For j = 1 To nColumnas
                
            tx.Write Ht.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value
            If j < nColumnas Then tx.Write vbTab
                
        Next j
                
        tx.WriteLine
    
    Next i
    
    tx.Close
    
    Set obj = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "El txt se ha generado con exito..."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tu problema se reduce a como mostrar el número sin el 0 significativo, se me ocurre que puede verificar la parte entera del número, si es 0 retornas el número convertido a cadena pero sin el primer caracter:

```
Function formatear_numero(numero)
    If Int(numero) = 0 Then
        formatear_numero = Right(Str(numero), Len(Str(numero)) - 1)
    Else
        formatear_numero = Str(numero)
    End If
End Function
```

Para aplicar la función podrías hacer:

```
tx.Write formatear_numero(Ht.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo mejor es que pongas los números como necesites y luego salves el archivo como TXT pero con el separador decimal cambiado.

Por ejemplo, este es mi archivo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El formato de celda que tengo aplicado a todas es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es uno personalizado que siempre muestra 4 decimales y oculta el valor cero en aquellos valores inferiores a la unidad en la parte entera (la última columna).

Después, lo salvo como txt pero la macro primero cambia los separadores decimales, forzando que el punto sea el separador decimal y la coma el de millares:

```
'cambiamos separadores decimales
With Application
    .DecimalSeparator = "."
    .ThousandsSeparator = ","
    .UseSystemSeparators = False
End With

'salvamos a txt
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="D:\rutacarpeta\test.txt", _
    FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False

'restauramos los separadores decimales del sistema
Application.UseSystemSeparators = True
```

Esto genera un archivo TXT justo como lo deseas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]